# Is there a way to partly make an ethernet cable wireless?

Tags: wireless-networking, home-networking, ethernet, wireless-access-point

I have two AP's, one in each house on my ranch. The houses are about 20m apart. One AP is sitting in a window facing the other house, but the other is deep within the second house. My internet router is situated next to the later AP.

Is there an easy way to connect these two AP´s wirelessly?

Comment: What you're looking for is a wireless bridge, preferably with some sort of directional antenna.

Comment: @Iszi but a wireless bridge is router-router. What about access point to router? making it wireless for part of the way then back to a wire.

Comment: @barlop A bridge is most commonly access point to access point. Usually the access point is built into a router, but that has no effect on the bridging part.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz  Great point..makes sense.  But, you say "most commonly". Is there any time a wireless bridge isn't for that? when?

Comment: Just as a heads up to @user105256, if you look at the related questions, the second question from the top has some good info  Some APs have this wireless bridge feature, some don't.  Lots of companies strongly suggest using APs of the same brand when you do this Wireless Bridging, and I'm assuming that's what you have.  The setup you want is this: http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/images/9/9b/Repeater_Bridge.jpg  The left side is House #2 with the modem, router, and access point, and the right side is House #1, the house that you want receiving the signal from House #2, I'm assuming.

Answer (score 2):

Please find out if your Routers support a standard caller WDS - Wireless Distribution System, which allows you to facilitate something called "Bridge Mode". Drawback is, that you might only use the weak WEP encryption, if devices are from different vendors.

Answer (score -1):

You can try following Scott Hanselman's example of doing this here:

[Configuring two wireless routers with one SSID at home for free roaming](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ConfiguringTwoWirelessRoutersWithOneSSIDNetworkNameAtHomeForFreeRoaming.aspx)

Comment: That won't help. He needs a way to connect the two wireless devices to each other.